# Android Studio Missing essential plugin: org.jetbrains.android ( Mac )

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android in my **MAC** swifter.

How I can fix it in Mac!

Answer (score 1):

Try to run mdfind disabled_plugins.txt in MacOS, then delete the disabled_plugins.txt file

Source: https://github.com/snapcrafters/android-studio/issues/81

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

u have to remove the disabled_plugins.txt file from ur mac pc

1. for mac -: Go to /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio
2. for windows -: Go to C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio\disabled_plugins.txt
3. if u have find it then delete this file

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot for the solution and finally found the following and it resolved the issue:

run the following command in the terminal:

rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio*